# Letting admin see all posts by all users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails and programming noob here. I am a teacher trying to create a god mode where I can view/edit etc posts of my students, however, students should be only able to view their own posts with this in the posts controller:

```
def index
@posts = Post.where(user_id:current_user)  
end
```

But how do I create an index for me to see everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `AdminController` with the following index method.

```
def index
  if params[:user_id]
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

This method will show posts of a certain user if the url parameter `user_id` is set and shows all posts on the system if the url parameter is not specified.

I would recommend using pagination like `kaminari` for example.